# Having different bundler Gemfiles for different platforms (option in config file is not used)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am using Ruby 1.9.3 (mingw) on Windows 7; . I have created specific gemfile for it: `Gemfile.mingw`. Then I set a config option:

```
bundle config --local gemfile Gemfile.mingw
```

Then I check this options is saved:

```
$ bundle config
Settings are listed in order of priority. The top value will be used.
gemfile
  Set for your local app (c:/*****/.bundle/config): "Gemfile.mingw"
```

Then I run `bundle install` ... just to see it still tries to install gems from default `Gemfile`.

Of course, when I run `bundle install --gemfile=Gemfile.mingw` it works properly. But seems it does not obey local configuration!

Tested with bundler versions 1.1.5, 1.2.0.rc2.

I also tried to set gemfile config option to full path, does not work as well, I cannot believe this feature is not working, probably I am just doing something wrong.

Comment: I tested this workflow on Ubuntu and it does not work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, the only response I found is a comment on a similar bug:

> Unfortunately, by the time Bundler loads the config file, it is too late. You need to set the Gemfile using BUNDLE_GEMFILE=Gemfile.sj bundle install, or using bundle install --gemfile Gemfile.sj.

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/1315

Looks like pretty a strange feature, it allows to config alternative gemfile but it is not used.